# Load moving mouse cursor for 3-4 secs when clicked on link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to know how can i stop the user from performing any task on the website for 3-4 secs when he clicks on a link.
I have a condition that when i click on a particular link/button it should download a file and till then the user is not allowed to access the page.
Can someone tell me how can i show the BUSY MOUSE CURSOR on the page when the user clicks the link.???

Answer (score 0):

You can create an overlay div for the page body and set it's cursor css property to "wait"

```
<body>
   <div class="wait-overlay" style="display:none;"></div>
</body>

.wait-overlay
{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
  background: rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.12);
  cursor: wait;
}
```

and with a script show it and then hide after operation is completed, or show and hide it with some timeout like

```
  divObject.show();
  setTimeout(3000, function(){  divObject.hide() });
```